# Why cant the compiler infer the type for me? (aka Smarter SmartEnumerable)

Tags: c#, generics

I am using Jon Skeet's very clever [SmartEnumerable](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/07/27/smart-enumerations.aspx). I recommend checking it out if you haven't already seen it.

The class is defined :

```
public class SmartEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<SmartEnumerable<T>.Entry>
```

The constructor is :

```
public SmartEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
```

and you use it by saying :

```
new SmartEnumerable<Cat>(myCats);  // where myCats is IEnumerable<Cat>
```

Now I'd really like to have the compiler infer I've got an array of cats and be able to just say :

```
new SmartEnumerable(myCats);
```

However this gives me a compiler error :

> The type arguments for method
>   'MiscUtil.Collections.SmartEnumerable.SmartEnumerable(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

I'm not clear exactly why this is. is there any way around it. Why can't it see I'm using `IEnumerable<Cat>` and infer from that. Can i change anythin to make it recognize the type I'm using?

I'd really like some way to construct a SmartEnumerable without having to specify the type - because I'm primarily using it for UI in ASP.NET MVC where I don't always have `includes` for the types and rely on `var` to get me a reference. I end up having to include types just to be able to use SmartEnumerable - which reduces its elegance.

Oh and I would have just emailed John directly but he'll probably reply faster here anyway :-)

---

`<font color=white>skeet skeet skeet, jon, jon, jon, jon skeet, skeet jon, skeetster, skeetmeister</font>`

Comment: Is this question up for the dubious honor of "post that mentions The Skeetster the most"?

Comment: Clever use of the Skeet-signal to get his attention.  Look behind you. He'll appear without making a sound.

Comment: oh no! my secret hidden skeet-signal text is visible ;-)

Comment: it would seem that even Jon can't track himself on SO when he's asleep

Comment: That's okay - I rely on my minions to provide perfect answers for me ;) To that end, thank you Bryan and Jared...

Answer (score 6):

Try this code

```
public static class SmartEnumerable {
  public static SmartEnumerable<T> Create<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) {
    return new SmartEnumerable<T>(source);
  }
}

void Example() {
  IEnumerable<string> myCats = GetMyCats();
  var se = SmartEnumerable.Create(myCats);
}
```

Your code is failing because C# is not able to infer generic arguments on a constructor.  But C# is more than capable of infering generic arguments on other methods.

In C# it's perfectly legal to have a class where the names only differ by the generic arguments.  Foo and Foo<T> for example (under the hood they're actually different names).  So the above sample will work for most scenarios.  I personally use it whenever I define a generic class where the constructors take enough arguments to infer the full type.

Comment: trying to play some more, but still getting : Error 44 Using the generic type 'MiscUtil.Collections.SmartEnumerable<T>' requires '1' type arguments - on the myCats line

Comment: What is the exact type of myCats?

Comment: IEnumerable<Cat> - well actually its of type 'InfoPanelEntry[]' but thats boring. I tried IEnumerable<string> myCats = null; to get that exact [compile time] error

Comment: @jaredpar - still no worky with jon's class. try downloading the SmartEnumerable class from the link at the top. your code may compile as it - but not in conjunction with the constructor and class definition i included above

Comment: @Simon: This should definitely work, with Jared's extra code (I will include something like this in MiscUtil at some point soon; it clearly makes sense to use type inference here).

Comment: @jon i must be doing something stupid. i'm not stupid though - i moved out of Basingstoke while I could :-) live in LA now. couldnt get it to compile with the rest of your class, i'm not saying it doesnt work as is. i do like the extension method though because it parallels ToArray() and ToList()

Comment: Will add it in MiscUtil and give an example in the usage page... easier than working out what's going wrong for you.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with JaredPar. I wanted to point out that you could also do an extension method:

```
public static SmartEnumerable<T> AsSmart<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new SmartEnumerable<T>(source);
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
var smartEnumerable = myCats.AsSmart();
```

(The example sounds kind of funny)

**Edit**:

Per Jon Skeet, I renamed `ToSmart` to `AsSmart`.

Comment: this one works :) i like this one. makes me wonder about other ways of doing it. i was just trying to think about the generics aspects, so didn't even TRY to think out of the box. i guess you could probably do an explicit cast convertor too (?) but thats a little icky syntactically

Comment: @bryan - our cats pretty smart so i can relate - http://ike.simonweaver.com. i've been using 'cat', 'dog', 'mouse' as variable names since i was about 8 years old despite never having had any of them as pets till now. i guess hamster is a bit long to type when you dont have intellisense

Comment: This is nice too. Will include something similar. I'd still like a better name than "SmartEnumerable" but I can't think of anything...

Comment: @jon I cant think of anything fun, or even a good boring name but i'll keep thinking. also curious which of your methods of finding skeetposts led you to find mine... ;-) either way being able to do ToSmart() is invaluable for MVC UI coding when using var

Comment: I think I'll call it AsSmartEnumerable rather than ToSmartEnumerable - it wraps it rather than immediately evaluating. Must check the implementation too.

Comment: (Of SmartEnumerable, I mean. The extension method is fine.)

Answer (score 3):

A quick update - this is now available in MiscUtil itself. As per the example on the [usage page](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html):

```
// Old way
foreach (SmartEnumerable<string>.Entry entry in
                 new SmartEnumerable<string>(list))

// Better way
foreach (SmartEnumerable<string>.Entry entry in
                SmartEnumerable.Create(list))

// Best way (C# 3.0)
foreach (var entry in list.AsSmartEnumerable())
```

Comment: great! thanks jon. this is helping a TONNE for MVC UI work. really elegant solution. i always wondered why there was no way to get the index, but always just complained instead of fixing it. back to reading your book on my new Kindle 2 :-)

Comment: My pleasure - and glad it's helping. I didn't know my book was available on the Kindle. Cool :) Hope you enjoy it.